# How to query Strapi and Graphql by urlSlug

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am using Strapi v4 with Graphql but I have some issue when trying to query

I am not able to query by urlSlug

does not work

```
query GetTutorial($urlSlug: String!) {
    tutorial(urlSlug: "demo-post") {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          body
        }
    }
}
```

However I am able to query by id

```
query GetTutorial($id: ID!) {
    tutorial(id: 1) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          body
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason that Graphql is not able to query by urlSlug

Comment: Please share the complete schema/content structure of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Using Strapi v4, you can only fetch one item using its ID. If you want to filter with other fields, you have to use a findMany query. Then you pick the first item of the returned array.

Example:

```
query GetTutorial($urlSlug: String!) {
    tutorials(filters: {urlSlug: {eq: $urlSlug}}) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          body
        }
    }
}
```